# Store sorting order in the database in the gridview gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I want to insert into database user custom sorting. So, users sort rows in the gridview however they like, and I store number of rows in the database. 
Notice: this gridview is conditional based on foreign key. like: Customer / orders.

For all customer I need to insert sorting order of their orders starting with 1.

Comment: Didn't try anything, since do not know where to start. What I can do is sorting on the front-end.

Comment: "Didn't try anything," - there's your problem!

Comment: Are you trying to save the sort order of the table for each customer? And you want to insert this data in a table with which sort order to come first second like that? am I correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct. I need to insert sorting number for orders for each customer.

Answer (score -1):

This seems strange.  I suppose in your business logic you could define an enumeration for various sorting options something like.

```
 public enum SortDescription
 {
      None,
      OrdersAsc,
      OrdersDesc,
      //Some other option?
 }
```

Internally the enums are integers and can be stored in the database easily in a tinyint column?

Then you could look up this enum prior to applying your sorting in the business layer

Comment: You misunderstood the question. Think of a playlist in Windows Media Player; the user rearranges the mp3's, and want that order to be saved in DB. And the order is the same when the playlist is opened again.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem how did you solved it. Please reply